# thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42016898)

Tags: android, ontouch

I am making slide puzzle game but dont know where the exception is occurring and app get crashes. I use Logcat and found that after calling onTouch() multiple times it get crashed .Following is the code

```
public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){
   float temp;
    Log.d("Puz","onTouch1 ");
    x= event.getX();
    y= event.getY();
    fl1=0;
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float x1=max_x/no_b,y1=max_y/no_b;
                cur_x=x-x%x1;
                cur_y=y-y%y1;
                x_p=(int)cur_x/(int)x1;
                y_p=(int)cur_y/(int)y1;
                cur_x=x_p*(int)x1;
                cur_y=y_p*(int)y1;
                b_i=cur_x;
                b_j=cur_y;
                if(x_p+1<no_b&&cha_c[x_p+1][y_p]==-1){
                    x_m_f=b_i;
                    x_m_t=b_i+2*x_di;
                    y_m_f=b_j;
                    y_m_t=b_j+y_di;
                    set=2;
                }
                else if(x_p-1>-1&&cha_c[x_p-1][y_p]==-1){
                    x_m_f=b_i-x_di;
                    x_m_t=b_i+x_di;
                    y_m_f=b_j;
                    y_m_t=b_j+y_di;
                    set=0;
                }
                else if(y_p+1<no_b&&cha_c[x_p][y_p+1]==-1){
                    x_m_f=b_i;
                    x_m_t=b_i+x_di;
                    y_m_f=b_j;
                    y_m_t=b_j+2*y_di;
                    set=3;
                }
                else if(y_p-1>-1&&cha_c[x_p][y_p-1]==-1){
                    x_m_f=b_i;
                    x_m_t=b_i+x_di;
                    y_m_f=b_j-y_di;
                    y_m_t=b_j+y_di;
                    set=1;
                }
                else
                    x_p=-1;
                pre_x=x;
                pre_y=y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            int temp_x,temp_y;
            if(x_p!=-1) {
                if (set == 0 && x_m_f + x_di > cur_x + x_di / 2) {
                    cha_c_p[x_p - 1][y_p] = cha_c_p[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c_p[x_p][y_p] = null;
                    cha_c[x_p - 1][y_p] = cha_c[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p] = -1;
                    ////temp_x=(cha_c[x_p - 1][y_p]-1)%no_b;
                   // temp_y=(cha_c[x_p - 1][y_p]-1)/no_b;
                    //cha_c_p[x_p - 1][y_p] = Bitmap.createBitmap(test, temp_x * (int)x_di, temp_y * (int)y_di, (int)x_di-2, (int)y_di-2);
                } else if (set == 2 && x_m_f + x_di < cur_x + x_di / 2) {
                    cha_c_p[x_p + 1][y_p] = cha_c_p[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c_p[x_p][y_p] = null;
                    cha_c[x_p + 1][y_p] = cha_c[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p] = -1;
                   // temp_x=(cha_c[x_p + 1][y_p]-1)%no_b;
                    //temp_y=(cha_c[x_p + 1][y_p]-1)/no_b;
                    //cha_c_p[x_p + 1][y_p] = Bitmap.createBitmap(test, temp_x * (int)x_di, temp_y * (int)y_di, (int)x_di-2, (int)y_di-2);
                } else if (set == 1 && y_m_f + y_di > cur_y + y_di / 2) {
                    cha_c_p[x_p ][y_p- 1] = cha_c_p[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c_p[x_p][y_p] = null;
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p - 1] = cha_c[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p] = -1;
                   // temp_x=(cha_c[x_p][y_p- 1]-1)%no_b;
                    //temp_y=(cha_c[x_p][y_p- 1]-1)/no_b;
                    //cha_c_p[x_p][y_p-1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(test, temp_x * (int)x_di, temp_y * (int)y_di, (int)x_di-2, (int)y_di-2);
                } else if (set == 3 && y_m_f + y_di < cur_y + y_di / 2) {
                    cha_c_p[x_p ][y_p + 1] = cha_c_p[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c_p[x_p][y_p] = null;
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p + 1] = cha_c[x_p][y_p];
                    cha_c[x_p][y_p] = -1;
                    //temp_x=(cha_c[x_p][y_p+ 1]-1)%no_b;
                    //temp_y=(cha_c[x_p][y_p+ 1]-1)/no_b;
                    //cha_c_p[x_p ][y_p+1] = Bitmap.createBitmap(test, temp_x * (int)x_di, temp_y * (int)y_di, (int)x_di-2, (int)y_di-2);
                }
            }
            x_p = -1;
            break;
    }
    if(x_p!=-1&&pre_x!=x&&pre_y!=y) {
        temp = cur_x + x - pre_x;
        if (temp >= x_m_f && temp + x_di <= x_m_t)
            cur_x =  temp;
        temp = cur_y + y - pre_y;
        if (temp >= y_m_f && temp + y_di <= y_m_t)
            cur_y = temp;
    }
    pre_x=x;
    pre_y=y;
    Log.d("Puz","onTouch2 ");
    return true;
}
```

Following are the results I got in Logcat

```
 03-07 22:08:04.746  19758-19785/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ ye run() 2
03-07 22:08:04.756  19758-19785/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ ye touch ke bad
03-07 22:08:04.756  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch1
03-07 22:08:04.756  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch2
03-07 22:08:04.766  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch1
03-07 22:08:04.766  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch2
03-07 22:08:04.766  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch1
03-07 22:08:04.766  19758-19758/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver D/Puz﹕ onTouch2
03-07 22:08:04.766  19758-19785/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42016898)
03-07 22:08:04.776  19758-19785/com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14604
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1
            at com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver.SlideSolver$MyBringBackSurface.run(SlideSolver.java:340)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: There is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurring on line 340 of `SlideSolver.java`

Answer (score 0):

The two key log lines are:

1. `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=-1`
2. `com.sudoku.mohammed.slidepuzzlesolver.SlideSolver$MyBringBackSurface.run(SlideSolver.java:340)`

The first `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you are trying to access an array index that is not part of the array. 
ie. `int a[] = new int[3]` and you use one of the following `a[-1]`, `a[3]`, `a[4]` etc. the `a[i]` has as `i` accepted values `[0, 2]` in this example. Or generally `[0, length)`

The second points exactly the line where this error happens `SlideSolver.java:340` which is `filename:line`

FYI. To show the line numbers in your IDE right click at the left gray bar.